# PHP STMT MySQL query returning LIKE results when set to equals

Tags: php, mysql

maybe I'm missing something obvious but I am not getting the results I would expect from this query. I'm getting what I would expect from a non-strict LIKE query.

```
public function get_product_list_by_title($title){
    $result = ARRAY();
    $stmt = $this->cn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name`, `price`, `comments` FROM Products WHERE `name` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $title);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $id,
        $name,
        $price,
        $notes
    );
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result[] = Array(
            "id" => $id,
            "name" => $name,
            "price" => $price,
            "notes" => $notes
        );
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

For instance if I searched "3" I would get every item with a 3 at the beginning (and possibly more - its a small data set)

Any ideas why?

Comment: What kind of column is `name`? It looks like you may be comparing an integer to a string, which results in an implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is a varchar being compared with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, `$title` is a string, and the `name` column is a `VARCHAR`. But when you bind `$title` like this

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $title);
```

you forcibly convert it to an integer. Change that line to

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
```

In `bind_param`, `"i"` means the parameter is passed as an integer, while `"s"` treats it as a string.

Comment: Thank you,  I just couldn't see the wood for the trees with that one, can't believe I missed it!